# very simple string encryption

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wanting to create my own extremely simple encryption for some text in python. Its only to deter people if they find the file i want to encrypt. I have this code below that could do that however it would take forever to code it the way im doing it and im sure its not the most efficient. I was wondering if there is a way to do this using much less code. (a,b,c are not the only charicters i will use btw. Also im fine copying/pasting the random text myself)

```
def encrypt(text):
    return str(text).replace("a", "3tpkDWCiXw").replace("b", "moOK4LWTUx").replace("c", "qqN9zTb9nR")

def decrypt(text):
    return str(text).replace("3tpkDWCiXw", "a").replace("moOK4LWTUx", "b").replace("qqN9zTb9nR", "c")

encrypted = encrypt("abc")

print(encrypted)

decrypted = decrypt(encrypted)

print(decrypted)
```

Thanks in advance as it will also help me with other things, not just this small project.
PS i just want this to be simple like the example given because i dont want/need more complicated encryption.

Edit: Another reason I'm not using more complicated encryption is because whenever i copy the code and try to do it myself i get an error. Also i did install cryptography but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: You're going to recursively replace stuff in previous replaces, the way you have it now. Don't replace. Build it from ch in text. (also use the looping structures already available in python. However -- if you use real encryption is might be easier, take up less space, and be safer. It can't be hard for someone to notice the same 8 character tokens recurring so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Caesar Cipher:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Caesar Cipher Encryption and Decryption tool.

# Introduction
print('\nHow to use:\n\n')
print('Encrypt:\n')
print('\tEnter your encryption key (1-25)\n')
print('\tThen, enter the message to encrypt.\n\n')

print('Decrypt:\n')
print('\tEnter the decryption key.\n')
print('\tThen, paste the encrypted message.')

print('\n\nEnter "q" or "quit" to exit.\n')

# Every possible symbol that can be encrypted/decrypted:
SYMBOLS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !?.~`@#$%^&*)("
message = ''
mode = ''

# User enters the mode
currentMode = input("Mode: [encrypt] or [decrypt]: ")

# ENCRYPT settings
if currentMode == 'e'.lower() or currentMode == 'encrypt'.lower():
    mode = 'encrypt'
    key = int(input('Encryption Key: '))
    while key >= len(SYMBOLS) or key <= 0:
        print('Please enter an encryption key between 1-' + str(len(SYMBOLS) - 1))
        key = int(input('Encryption Key: '))
    message = input('What would you like to encrypt?\n')

# DECRYPT settings
elif currentMode == 'D' or currentMode == 'd' or currentMode == 'decrypt' or currentMode == 'DECRYPT':
    mode = 'decrypt'
    key = int(input('Decryption Key: '))
    while key >= len(SYMBOLS) or key <= 0:
        print('Please enter a decryption key between 1-' + str(len(SYMBOLS) - 1))
        key = int(input('Decryption Key: '))
    message = input('Paste the encrypted text below:\n')

# Quit
elif currentMode == 'Q' or currentMode == 'q' or currentMode == 'quit' or currentMode == 'QUIT':
    exit()

# Store encrypted / decrypted message:
translated = ''

for symbol in message:
    if symbol in SYMBOLS:
        symbolIndex = SYMBOLS.find(symbol)

        # Perform encryption / decryption
        if mode == 'encrypt':
            translatedIndex = symbolIndex + key
        if mode == 'decrypt':
            translatedIndex = symbolIndex - key

        # Handle wraparound if needed:
        if translatedIndex >= len(SYMBOLS):
            translatedIndex = translatedIndex - len(SYMBOLS)
        elif translatedIndex < 0:
            translatedIndex = translatedIndex + len(SYMBOLS)

        translated = translated + SYMBOLS[translatedIndex]
    else:
        # Append the symbol without encrypting / decrypting:
        translated = translated + symbol

# Output text
if mode == 'encrypt':
    print('\nYour ENCRYPTED message:')
elif mode == 'decrypt':
    print('\nThe secret message is:')

# Ciphertext
print('\n\t' + translated + '\n')
```

You can also check out the Affine or Transposition Cipher which are both fairly simple (but more complex than Caesar Cipher)